# NTML Headers don't get send by Firefox or IE

Tags: asp.net, firefox, firebug, ntlm

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET App and I want to get the Username & Workstation of the current User/Request.
I want to use NTLM and the `Authorization` with the `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` HTTP-Headers.

I've enabled these settings in Firefox 4:

```
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris = http://localhost
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris = http://localhost
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris = http://localhost
network.ntlm.send-lm-response = true
```

But I don't get the Authorization Header in Firebug or in my app (using `Request.Headers`).
I've also tried with IE 9, but it doesn't send it either.

Am I missing something here?

I thought they get send automatically with each request once I've enabled it for the trusted uris and they are send automatically in IE, too, at least in intranets.

The ASP app uses forms authentication and it should stay this way as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser sends NTLM/Negotiate headers only when he gets 401 error with a corresponding `WWW-Authenticate` header (NTLM and/or Negoriate). Then browser silently makes one more request with a headers your are looking for:

- In case of `NTLM` before this silent request you will be asked for login/pwd. Then if browser receive 401 error again, login/pwd prompt window pop-ups again. And this will repeate until either correct credentials or Cancel would pressed. Each request from the second, the application will get authentication headers.
- In case of `Negotiate` you will be asked for login/pwd only if browser were unable to authorize you. The rest is the same as that for NTLM.

In any other requests these headers are not sent. As well as when anonymous authentication enabled and/or windows one disabled for requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you have anonymous authentication enabled in IIS, it will use that by default.  In order to use NTLM you have to disable anonymous authentication.

Comment: Then I get "HTTP-Error 401.2 - Unauthorized", because the Header is still not send in FF. works with IE, but the header is also missing

Comment: @Simon: From a fresh FireFox installation, we only set `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and that makes it work.  One trick is that it's a COMMA separated list.  If you have multiple URL's separated by `;` or any other separator, it won't work.

Comment: Nope, no effect. I only have the exact same configuration as above and I tried to only set your parameter. I've also restarted my Firefox multiple times and still getting the 401.2